# Plotting homemade segmented function went haywire

Tags: python, function, matplotlib, plot

I needed to plot a homemade segmented function defined as follow:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def f(x):
    if x >=0 and x <=1:  
        return  2*np.sqrt(x)
    elif x > 1:
        return 1+x

x = np.linspace(0.0, 100)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
plt.show()
```

The error message was: 
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
Then I followed python's suggestion and changed the implementation of the function to this:

```
def f(x):
    if x.all() >=0 and x.all() <=1:  
        return 2*np.sqrt(x)
    elif x.all() > 1:
        return 1+x
```

This time, the figure showed up but it was not the curve that the defined function intended. It's a wrong curve. It just plotted the 2*np.sqrt(x) part. I can really use some help, and many thanks to any one who lends a hand.

Answer (score 0):

if your intention is a piecewise function, you should use `np.where()`

```
def f(x):
    return np.where(np.logical_and(x >= 0, x <= 1), 2*np.sqrt(x), x+1)

x = np.linspace(0.0, 100)
plt.plot(x, f(x))
```

or simply use list comprehension

```
def f(x):
    if x >=0 and x <=1:  
        return  2*np.sqrt(x)
    elif x > 1:
        return 1+x

x = np.linspace(0.0, 100)
plt.plot(x, [f(i) for i in x])
```

also, you may want to get more plotting samples by setting the `num` parameter in `np.linspace()` higher

Comment: It worked. You are awesome, Bill. I don't know why the comparison "x >= 0, x <= 1" caused error in my code and didn't in yours.

Comment: @Ignorant The error came from the `and` operator, not the comparison operators